# How to calculate gradients in dihedral/torsion bond?

Tags: classical-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, potential-energy

Given 4 consecutively bonded atoms (A-B-C-D), how do i calculate the vector along which a force should be applied for the interior 2 atoms?

The dihedral is described by vectors r1, r2, and r2 between the 4 atoms, as seen in the image below.

Assuming the potential energy is lowest when the torsion angle is 0, I can calculate the unit vectors along which the exterior atoms will move:

$$\Delta_A = m = \frac{r1 \times r2}{|r1 \times r2|}$$
$$\Delta_D = n = \frac{r2 \times r3}{|r2 \times r3|}$$

This seems rather intuitive.
For the interior atoms, I could simply take the negative of the sum of m and n, but that does not seem.. correct.
How do i find the vectors for the interior atoms $\Delta_B$ and $\Delta_C$?

[image: Sketch of formula for exterior atoms]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.